# JMS options in Apache hop

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-hop

In order to satisfy a certain criterium, there is a need to publish a message to an existing ActiveMQ instance. Currently we use different software and a JMS-based connection to publish and read messages.

I did find about the [additional plugins](https://github.com/project-hop/hop-plugins/) where MQTT is listed. We don't prefer to use that protocol if not required.

I could not find any plugins for Apache Hop that deal with receiving/sending over JMS, so is that an option?

Answer (score 2):

I will unfortunately have to disappoint you in this case.
As far as I know no one has written a plugin to support ActiveMQ yet.

You can create a ticket on our [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HOP/) to request a community member to create such a transform(s). Or we can support you through our mailing-list if you have specific questions when writing a plugin to support it.

Comment: Checking out the jira requests I already saw a similar request was made way earlier (which mentiones AMQ and RMQ). Should I just update that one or create a new request?

Comment: Right, I guess that ticket also covers your request. So you can bump that with your specifics if you want